# Why memory list contains worked as case insensitive?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, .net-core

i have a memory list and objects from MySQL

requiredUserNames: calls ***"where users.Contains(us.Username)"*** why it worked as case insensitive contains where users is a memory list object (normal c# object) while the second one worked normally as C# works as case sensitive:

```
var users = (from u in _dbContext.MyUser
             select new 
             {
                 UserName = u.UserName
             }).ToList();

var requiredUserNames = (from us in _dbContext.NextUsers
                    // users is a memory list and not a database list why executed as case insensitive
                   where users.Contains(us.Username)
                   select new { Username = us.Username}).ToList();


var requiredUserNames02 = (from us in _dbContext.NextUsers
                        // here working normally as case sensitive
                     where users.FindIndex((usr) => usr.Username.Equals(us.Username)) > -1
                   select new { Username = us.Username }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users is a local list, that is true. BUT, _dbContext.NextUsers is remote and you are asking your MySQL instance something like:

```
select us.* from NextUsers us where us.UserName in ('theNameFromLocalList','...')
```

IOW it is MySQL that does the insensitive search. If you prevent that, then it would be more costly but:

```
var requiredUserNames = (from us in _dbContext.NextUsers.AsEnumerable()
                    // users is a memory list and not a database list why executed as case insensitive
                   where users.Contains(us.Username)
                   select new { Username = us.Username}).ToList();
```